# Software design pattern videos?

Tags: design-patterns, video, theory

I have tried searching Lynda and YouTube for design pattern videos. I understand videos (voice and live pictures) a lot better than boring black text against white background. Can you suggest me quality design pattern videos? By quality I am referring to videos created by people who actually understand what they are talking about, and can speak clear English.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

SoureMaking has very good [video's here](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns). [Here is another](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1xUz1fp23TQ) from YouTube

[SOLID principle](http://www.dimecasts.net/Casts/ByTag/SOLID%20Principle) videos

Comment: I downloaded the SourceMaking videos and was a bit disappointed. The content seems pretty good so far, but the production values are poor. A bit of a shame, though I guess you can't expect too much for $50. It's also worth noting that some of the videos are on YouTube.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest [Head First Design Patterns](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596007126) if you have not already read it. It is so visually rich and done in comic book style that I guess you would like it over videos.

Comment: +1 A fun read, while the GoF one is a bit dull indeed.